# Exclude a field/property from the database with Entity Framework 4 & Code-First

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, poco

I will like to know that is there a way to exclude some fields from the database? For eg:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }

    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarried { get; set; }

    public string AddressAs { get; set; }
}
```

How can I exclude the AddressAs field from the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the current version the only way to exclude a property is to explicitly map all the other columns:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().MapSingleType(e => new {
  e.Id,
  e.Name,
  e.FatherName,
  e.IsMale,
  e.IsMarried
});
```

Because AddressAs is not referenced it isn't part of the Entity / Database.

The EF team is *considering* adding something like this:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().Exclude(e => e.AddressAs);
```

I suggest you tell leave a comment on the EFDesign blog, requesting this feature :)

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: I realized that the only way to do it as of today is the way you mentioned. I posted it on EFDesign blog a long back: http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx

Comment: Would be a real bonus if they add a `.Exclude()`

Comment: Is there a way to exclude a particular field from all classes in a model using the T4 template?

Answer (score 80):

for future reference: you can use data annotations 
[MSDN EF - Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped)

```
[NotMapped]        
public string AddressAs { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 35):

I know this is an old question but in case anyone (like me) comes to it from search...

Now it is possible in entity framework 4.3 to do this.  You would do it like so:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().Ignore(e => e.AddressAs);
```

Comment: Or in VB `builder.Entity(Of Employee).Ignore(Function(e) e.AddressAs)`

Comment: Would this be global? I mean, what if I want to do it for just this one call? Can I turn it back on, so to speak?

Comment: Yes still useful. you just saved me 40 minutes of research.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to add the column you want to ignore as a [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) in the DbContext:

```
builder.Entity<Employee>().Property<string>("AddressAs");
```

Then you can query on that column like so:

```
context.Employees.Where(e => EF.Property<string>(e, "AddressAs") == someValue);
```