# Entity Framework Code First lazy loading non navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm using the entity framework code first CTP4.

Is it possible to lazy load non navigation properties like you can in NH 3.

A common example would be having a table containing a binary column. I only want to retrieve this column's data when I explicitly ask for that property in my code e.g. image.ImageData

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Just a guess. There is a Table Splitting approach, maybe it will help: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/

Comment: Yes this is what we used to do with NH before support for lazy loaded properties was added. Looks like the same will be true of EF code first.

Answer (score 2):

1. Vote [here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1798875-exclude-function-as-opposed-to-include)
2. Vote [here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1051513-lazy-loading-at-column-level?ref=title)
3. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707663/exclude-a-field-property-from-the-database-with-entity-framework-4-code-only)
4. Ugly workaround:

   ```
   public static void Main()
   {
     IEnumerable<MyTable> table;
     using (Entities context = new Entities())
     {
       var buffer =
         context.MyTable
         .Select(myTable => new
         {
           Id = myTable.Id,
           OtherColumn = myTable.OtherColumn
         })
         .ToArray();

       table = buffer
         .Select(t => new MyTable 
         {
           Id = t.Id, 
           OtherColumn = t.OtherColumn
         });
     }
   }
   ```

This will not select the rest of the fields.