# How to ignore a property when using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Entity Framework Code First will auto-create a table in the database base based on the Model.

Is there an attribute that will avoid this?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Add the [`[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx) attribute to the property.

Comment: Does this has the benefit (over fluent declaration) that annotated properties will (or should) be ignored by other data mappers/serializers, such as JSON serializers?

Answer (score 57):

Per the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572463/1037948) and [similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385738/1037948), in addition to `[NotMapped]` you can also specify it using the Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<TheModelAffected>().Ignore(t => t.TheIgnoredProperty);
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

`[NotMapped]` is the short version if you like conciseness. And of course, you would add:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

to your class.