# How Avoid migration separate data into two tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

In my code first app I do have a class "customer" and "address". My client class has Address class reference. for instance

```
class Customer{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Address address {get;set;}
}

class Address{
    public string street{get;set;}
    public string number{get;set;}
}
```

when I migrate these data I got one table customer with those columns:

```
name
address_street
address_number
```

It is great. My data is only in one table. It was perfect to me!.

However I need (for other reasons) add a ID for address.

```
class Address{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
    public string street{get;set;}
    public string number{get;set;}
}
```

in this case the migration split my customer table into customer and address table.

```
name
addressId
```

and

```
street
number
```

There is any annotation that could avoid this ? I really would like to have address data inside customer table.

Comment: Not sure why you don't go the normalized route: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, but you could add [NotMapped] to your Id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572442/how-to-ignore-a-property-when-using-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: What happens when someone has two addresses? Completely agreed with @SteveGreene that normalization is the way to go.

Comment: Guys I understand your point. Please note that this is a example to express my needs. The real data is not a address. is quite more complex. But i appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for code first to recognize this, you must mark the Address class as a [ComplexType]. Then Address will be tracked as part of a Customer object.

Just add the  [ComplexType] annotation into the address class

```
[ComplexType]
public class Address
{ 
    //...
}
```