# How to specify a property as calculated in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

In examples from Microsoft, they implicitly defined a calculated property by providing only accessor without mutator:

```
public string NormalProperty { get; set; }
public string CalculatedProperty
{
    get { return "foobar" + NormalProperty; }
}
```

I also want to have a mutator in CalculatedProperty, which automatically trims the "foobar" suffix and assigns the result back into NormalProperty.

```
public string CalculatedProperty
{
    get { return "foobar" + NormalProperty; }
    set { NormalProperty = value.Substring(6); }
}
```

The issue is, Entity Framework now considers CalculatedProperty a normal property, and create a column named "CalculatedProperty" in the database.

I do not want to workaround with this by using functions. Can it be done through Attributes/Fluent API? I am using EF 6.1.

Comment: which mode do you use? Code First, or Database first with edmx file? If it is the latter one, I may have a solution

Comment: I am building a new website from the ground up using Code First. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in your DataContext in code first

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Your_Class>().Ignore(x => x.CalculatedProperty); 
}
```

Comment: I read Gert Arnold's link above and solved the problem. Thanks for your answer anyway.