# Adding a virtual column to Table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the below dbcontext.cs and the corresponding table.cs which define the DAL in my MVC using entity framework.

The **List** table in my database does not have a column C but I would like the entity to get the ID,A,B values from DB and get the C from code. Is this possible if so what is the best approach.

The below code fails giving an exception "Invalid Coloumn C".

The other way I can think around is to declare another entity ex:**ListEntity2** and add the values after query from **ListEnity** which I guess is a good way but just wanted to know of any other possibilities.

**table.cs:**

```
 [Table("List")]
    public class ListEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        private string name;
        public virtual string C
        {
            get 
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
               name=value ;
            }
        }
    }
```

**dbcontext.cs:**

```
public DbSet<ListEntity> List { get; set; }
```

Comment: See [Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first), or consider using your entity models only as entity models and implement any alterations through inheritance, composition or extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the `NotMapped` attribute ([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

> [...] Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database mapping.

For example:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("List")]
public class ListEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    private string name;

    [NotMapped]
    public string C
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```