# Create a Class for extend Model Classes in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have a model class that has for example 3 properties and corresponding table in my data base.

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string prop1 {set; get;}
    public string prop2 {set; get;}
    public string prop3 {set; get;}
}
```

Now I want derived property that for example create using `prop1` and `prop3` :

```
prop4 = prop1 + prop3;
```

I want to extend `Person` to have `prop4`. I create a partial class for `Person` to have `prop4`:

```
public partial class Person
{
     public string prop4 {set; get;}
}
```

but when I run the application I got this error:

> Invalid column name 'prop4'

I change the above class like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel : Person
{
    public string prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

> Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Discriminator'.\r\nInvalid column name 'prop4'

but if I create a class like this every think will be ok:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string prop1 {set; get;}
    public string prop2 {set; get;}
    public string prop3 {set; get;}
    public string prop4 {set; get;}
}
```

but using this solution I should rewrite all properties in ViewModel classes. Is there any other ways?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NotMapped attribute or the fluent API Ignore method [Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first)