# Using the same class for Repository pattern and data handling in VM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, irepository

I have a class which is used in Entity Framowork and in my VMs;

The class:

```
public abstract class LegPartDbStructure
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("название1")]
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    [Column("название2")]
    public string Text2 { get; set; }

    [Column("id_метрики")]
    public int? Size { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("уровень_вложенности")]
    public int Level { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text1 + " " + Text2;
    }
}
```

Implementation of IRep:

```
[Table("БПВ_на_бедре_структура")]
public partial class BPVHipStructure :LegPartDbStructure, ILegPart
{

}

public class MySqlContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BPVHipStructure> BPVHipStructures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BPVHipCombo> BPVHipCombos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Metrics> Metrics { get; set; }
    public MySqlContext() : base("server=localhost;user=root;database=med_db;password=22222;") {

    }
}

public class BPVHipRepository : Repository<BPVHipStructure>
{
    public BPVHipRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<BPVHipStructure> LevelStructures(int level)
    {
        return dbContext.Set<BPVHipStructure>().Where(bpvhip => bpvhip.Level == level).ToList();
    }
}
```

Using in my VM (StructureSource i usi in ComboBox):

```
StructureSource = new ObservableCollection<LegPartDbStructure>(base.Data.BPVHips.LevelStructures(number).ToList());
```

Everything was fine until i needed to add one more field to LegPartDbStructure. The idea is to store a name from metrics instead of having only ids.

```
[Column("id_метрики")]
public int? Size { get; set; }
[Required]
[Column("уровень_вложенности")]
public int Level { get; set; }

public string Metrics { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
    return Text1 + " " + Metrics + " " + Text2;
}
```

But i can't do this because of 'Unknown column 'Extent1.Metrics' in 'field list'' - my table in db doesn't have this field. Does it mean I need to add extra class which has the same info, but stores metrics? How to add this logic properly?

---

**SOLUTION**:

I lust needed to add [Not Mapped] to my new field:

```
[NotMapped]
public string Metrics { get; internal set; }
```

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385738/5505949

Comment: try to drop and recreate your table.or set DB initializer DropIfModelChange

Comment: Thank you Karolis, it workes!