# How to add unsaved variable to class which also represents a SQL Server object?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have the following object declared in C# ASP.NET MVC, which represents an object in our Azure SQL Server database.

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Edited")]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime LastEditDateUTC { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public String Subject { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I would save this object to the SQL database:

```
Note note = new Note()
{
    // Fill out all the variables
};

try
{
    mySQLServer.mySQLTable.Add(note);
    mySQLServer.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Log
}
```

What I would like is to add one more variable to `Note` named `IsSelected`, but I would not like this variable to be saved to the SQL server's table when the `mySQLServer.SaveChanges()` method is called, because the `IsSelected` variable would be used with the UI only. Is there a Data Annotation property that can be added to `IsSelected` to accomplish this? Is this use case even possible?

Comment: Use a view model - [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Ideally you should use a view model. But if you decide to not go that approach, you can add the `[NotMapped]` attribute. See this [Ignoring a class property in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first/10385738#10385738)