# Don't insert inner objects in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a class:

```
public class Foo {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Child { get; set; }
}
```

When I insert into `Foo` via `context.Foos.Add(myFoo)`, a `Bar` is being inserted into the database if it is not null.

How can I prevent this from happening? Do I have to set Child to null prior to inserting into the context?

Comment: Perhaps this works for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385738

Comment: @inquisitive I want it to be mapped. I just don't want it to be created this one time

Comment: I don't know what is your use-case, but either set it to `null` if that's okay for you, or try detaching child entity from `DbContext`. I think EF Core should then skip (not try) inserting the entity.