# EF Code First exclude column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclude a field/property from the database with Entity Framework 4 & Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707663/exclude-a-field-property-from-the-database-with-entity-framework-4-code-first)

I am using EF 4 code-first.

Is there any method to exclude creating a column into the database?

For example I want to exclude the `Zip` column to be created.

```
public string Address { get; set; }
[StringLength(40)]
public string City { get; set; }
[StringLength(30)]
public string State { get; set; }
[StringLength(10)]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Thank you.

Comment: See this Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707663/exclude-a-field-property-from-the-database-with-entity-framework-4-code-first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `[NotMapped]` attribute to the property you want to exclude from the database:

```
public string Address { get; set; }

[StringLength(40)]
public string City { get; set; }

[StringLength(30)]
public string State { get; set; }

[StringLength(10)]
[NotMapped]
public string Zip { get; set; }
```